# HTTPS and MySql issues using Docker for local web development

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose, virtualhost

My goal is to have multiple sites/containers with different apache or PHP configurations running side-by-side and accessible by unique virtual hosts. This way I can quickly switch between sites/clients/containers as needed.

I currently use LAMP when developing websites and applications locally. Sometimes I need to install extra PHP packages or switch between PHP versions. Lately, I have needed to switch a lot and even had a site that needed Memcache installed. I have been looking into using Docker, I like the idea of having a configuration file that can be saved for each project so when a client comes back 6 months later I can quickly set up the same environment.

I have Docker setup and created a few containers to learn how to use it. But I have come across a few issues with my current configuration. My local setup is:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- LAMP (w/MySql)
- Apache with VirtualHosts

I read a bunch of tutorials, watched a few hours of videos on LinkedIn learning, and started with a WordPress setup to quickly confirm both the MySql and web containers worked. I found the following issues.

- I needed to stop my local MySql and Apache services. Running LAMP and docker side by side failed every time. Not an issue because the goal is to move to Docker.
- I work on multiple sites/clients every day so I will need multiple web containers running side by side using virtual hosts instead of 127.0.0.1. Every tutorial online shows one docker-compose configuration with web and MySql containers.
- Having a MySql container for each project is not ideal because of port conflicts. Instead, I would prefer to have a single MySql container for all projects or connect to the locally installed MySql service.
- I tried to create a single MySql container for all containers to connect to. It worked but I was not able to import a client's large 2 GB DB so I gave up and instead would like to use the locally installed MySql service. Tried but it looks like docker on Linux has issues connecting to the local machine.
- I need to be able to access the web containers via port 80 and 443 for both http and https. I don't need an SSL cert setup and the browser warning is fine each time I go to the virtual host via https. But there is something wrong with my client's docker-compose file because 443 is not available.

From what I have read and from playing around with docker-compose I have settled on the following configuration.

1. I created a docker-compose file with "nginx-proxy" and "mailhog" containers. I am using the image "jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine" from a tutorial I found so I can use a virtual host for each client's web container.
2. Each client will have its own web container but might be a different image for each based on their production environment.
3. Use the locally installed MySql service or one MySql container for all databases.

Main NGINX docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  # ngix so we can have multiple sites running with virtualhosts
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      #- "3305:3305"
      #- "8025:8025"
    extra_hosts:
      - "dockerhost:192.100.10.3"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

  # mailhog
  mailhog:
    container_name: mailhog
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports: 
      - 8025:8025 # web ui
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8025
    expose:
      - 8025

# stop here
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Clients docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

# containers/ instances
services:

  # wordpress container
  wordpress:
    container_name: clientname
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysqldb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wptest
      VIRTUAL_HOST: docker-second-text.local
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443

# stop here
volumes:
  wordpress: {}

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Recap, the two configuration files work. I can run two sites/web containers side by side with different files, DBs, and hostnames. What doesn't work is:

1. Using a MySql container with a large 2 GB database or connecting to the local MySql service.
2. Being able to access the container from port 443 via https.

I am open to a different configuration and any suggestions are appreciated. Again my goal is to have multiple sites/containers with different apache or PHP configurations running side-by-side and accessible by unique virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can´t use your apache and container at the same time is, you expose the ports in your docker-compose.yml. So the ports are blocked. Expose means you container will be accessable under hostIP:Port, but a port can be used only by one application at the same time.

I think, I have your requested setting running.
I use nginx as a reverse proxy, installed on the docker host, to expose the differtent container under subdmoains, eg. app1.example.com, app2.example.com

I use different docker networks for the container, so they stay isolated.

First create external docker networks:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.1.0/29 --gateway=192.168.1.1 app1net
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.1.8/29 --gateway=192.168.1.9 app2net
```

you can use smaller or bigger nets if needed. 
Don`t forget to allow traffic to and from the nets pass your host firewall.

A sample docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.3.2-php7.4-apache
    restart: always

    links:
      - db:db
    environment:
                  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
                  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
                  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: Pa$$w0rd
                  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
                  WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
    volumes:
        - ./html:/var/www/html
    networks:
            app1net:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.1.2

  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

      links:
        - db:db
      networks:
              app1net:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.1.3

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpressdb
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Pa$$w0rd
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
            app1net:
                    ipv4_address: 192.168.1.4

networks:
        app1net: 
                external: 
                        name: app1net
```

The different services are accessable via the 192.168.1.0/29 net from the host.

Next configure the nginx virtal server, but you could also use your apache as proxy:

NGINX proxy:

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80 http2;
    listen 1.2.3.4:443 ssl http2;
    server_name app1.example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate /ssl/sslcert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @wordpress;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri @phpmyadmin;
    }


    location @wordpress{
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2;
    }
    location @phpmyadmin{
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3;
    }

}
```

Apache2 proxy:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
    ServerName app1.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/sslcert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/privkey.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.2
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.2             
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName app1.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.2
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.2             
</VirtualHost>
```

You may have to edit the apache default config under /etc/apache2/ports.conf to set the listening ip/ports or disable apache complete. Thats why you can`t run both server at the same time. Apache is using them. But if you use apache as proxy this in not needed.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 127.0.0.1:443

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 127.0.0.1:443
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps...